# Weird image behaviour using Javascript and Canvas element

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-canvas

I am trying to make use of the output from a toDataURL call on a canvas element.

```
var snapshotjig = document.getElementById("snapParent");
var testOutput = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctxtest = testOutput.getContext('2d');
var imageTest = new Image();
var canvas = capture(video, scaleFactor);    

imageTest.src = canvas.toDataURL();
ctxtest.drawImage(imageTest,0,0,imageTest.width, imageTest.height);
snapshotjig.appendChild(testOutput);
```

for completion the capture code looks like this:

```
function capture(video, scaleFactor) {
    if(scaleFactor == null){
        scaleFactor = 1;
    }
    var w = video.videoWidth * scaleFactor;
    var h = video.videoHeight * scaleFactor;
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width  = w;
        canvas.height = h;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
    return canvas;
}
```

In the html there is a div element with the id "snapParent".
The capture function seems to work fine, but the instance I use toDataUrl and then try to draw that output I get varied results, at the moment I get a small portion of the image in my div element snapParent.
Not sure what is causing this or what I am doing wrong.

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to make use of the toDataUrl to take the image and use it in a function that will let me turn it into an interactive Jigsaw, this code takes a url at the moment, replacing it with the toDataUrl output should be trivial, I just cant work out why my image is being cropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to Pointy suggestion I found that the canvas I was using testOutput did not have its width and Height set, as such the defaults for the browser I am using are used which happen to be enough to show a small portion of the image. The context is not where you set the size, but Pointy's suggestion made me look again at dimension setting of the canvas, cheers bud.

I use the capture method to set the testOutput canvas sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me as if you forgot to set the width and height of your "ctxtest" canvas.

Comment: ctxtest is a context. So far as I am aware you do not set the width and height there.